# Django REST: queryset error type error int() must be a string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm trying to get all users who are employers.
So what I did was I filter the users where the id can be found in the "employer" field of any (other) user.
However this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

**View:**

```
# Get all employers
class Employers(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        #queryset = CustomUser.objects.all();
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(id__in=CustomUser.objects.filter(employer=id))    #this gives me an error
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Model (standard stuff):**

```
# CustomUser model
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    employer = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(selfself, app_label):
        return True;
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: what you are passing in `id` where the error occurs. I mean `int` or `object`?

Comment: @PruthviBarot: the builtin `id` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: @PruthviBarot id of CustomUser. So int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with an [**`F`**-expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to refer to another column:

```
from django.db.models import F

class Employers(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(employer=F('pk'))
```

This thus makes a query that looks like;

```
SELECT customuser.*
FROM customuser
WHERE customuser.employer = customuser.id
```

or you can filter the relation in reverse to get `CustomUser`s that employ at least one person:

```
class Employers(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(customuser__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This constructs a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customuser.*
FROM customuser
JOIN customuser u2 ON u2.employer = customuser.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this query isn't correct? Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this query selects customusers where their employer is the same as their id. So you only get the users who are their own employer? Whereas I simply want all employers.

Comment: @SJ19: in that case it is the latter. The question is, what are the employes of an employer? I would think then it refers to itself. But the second query lists all `CustomUser`s who have at least one `CustomUser` that has them as `employer`.

Comment: Employers don't have employers (null) :). Second query works! But I honestly have no clue what you're doing here, care to explain? Like what does customuser__isnull=False do, and what is distinct? There doesn't seem to be any reference to the employer field which I don't get.

Comment: @SJ19: no, but then it would perhaps be more elegant to link it to themselves, since then it is not a `NULLable` field, and moving "up" in the hierarcy is thus more elegant. Anyway, the latter should produce `customuser`s that have at least one employee.

Comment: @SJ19: it means we make a `LEFT OUTER` join on the `employer` relation in reverse, and because of the `__isnull=False` filter, it thus is a simle `INNER JOIN`. The `.distinct()` is necessary, since otherwise we would return the same `CustomUser` multiple times, one for each employee.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation! I have accepted your answer. Finally is there any good source learn how to translate SQL statements into django queries?

Comment: @SJ19: the Django documentation discusses this to some extent (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/). But I think one learns best by trying. You can inspect the query Django makes with `print(queryset.query)`, this often helps to understand the mechanism Django uses to translate the queryset to a database query.